# I am having trouble vaildating my code.I need my code to loop untill a valid answer is inputted

Tags: python, validation, loops

I am struggling with this piece of Python code. The problem is,when a user enters something wrong I need my code to keep looping until they input a valid answer.
This is how the code is supposed to work: User is prompted to choose a drink, then a cuisine, then a dish. After this, the program displays the order the user wanted.

```
Order = [ 'No drink', 'No food' ]
Yesses = [ 'y', 'yes', 'yep', 'okay', 'sure' ]
DRINK = 0
FOOD = 1

print("Welcome to Hungary house!")

print("")
print("First, let me get your drink order, if any.")

answer = input("Would you like something to drink? ").lower()

if answer in Yesses:
    print("What drink would you prefer?")
    print ("1: Fanta")
    print ("2: Coke")
    print ("3: Pepsi")
    print ("4: Sprite")

    choice = input("Please enter a drink from the menu above\n").lower()

    if choice == "1" or choice == "fanta":
        Order[DRINK] = "Fanta"
    if choice == "2" or choice == "coke":
        Order[DRINK] = "Coke"
    if choice == "3" or choice == "pepsi":
        Order[DRINK] = "Pepsi"
    if choice == "4" or choice == "sprite":
        Order[DRINK] = "Sprite"

print ("You have chosen: " + Order[DRINK])

print("")
print("Now, let me get your food order, if any.")

answer = input("Do you want any food (Y/N)? ").lower()
if answer in Yesses:
    answer = input("Do you want Italian,Indian or Chinese food?\n").lower()

    if answer == "indian":
        answer = input("Do you want Curry or Onion Bhaji?\n").lower()

        if answer == "curry":
            Order[FOOD] = "Curry"

            answer = input("With your curry, do you want Rice or Naan?\n").lower()
            if answer == "rice":
                Order.append("- with rice")
            if answer == "naan":
                Order.append("- with naan")

        if answer == "onion bhaji" or answer == "bhaji":
            Order[FOOD] = "Onion Bhaji"

            answer = input("With your bhaji, do you want Chili or Peppers?\n").lower()
            if answer == "chili":
                Order.append("- with chili")
            if answer == "peppers":
                Order.append("- with peppers")
    if answer == "chinese":
        answer = input("Do you want Chicken Wings or Noodles?\n").lower()

        if answer == "chicken wings" or answer == "wings":
            Order[FOOD] = "Chicken Wings"

            answer = input("With your wings, do you want Chips or Red Peppers?\n").lower()
            if answer == "chips":
                Order.append("- with Chips")
            if answer == "red peppers" or answer == "peppers":
                Order.append("- with Red Peppers")

        if answer == "noodles":
            Order[FOOD] = "Noodles"

            answer = input("With your noodles, do you want Meatballs or Chicken?\n").lower()
            if answer == "meatballs":
                Order.append("- with meatballs")
            if answer == "chicken":
                Order.append("- with chicken")
    if answer == "italian":
        answer = input("Do you want Pasta or Noodles?\n").lower()

        if answer == "pasta" or answer == "Pasta":
            Order[FOOD] = "Pasta"

            answer = input("With your Pasta, do you want Vegetarian Toppings or meat toppings?\n").lower()
            if answer == "vegetarian Toppings":
                Order.append("- with Vegetarian Toppings")
            if answer == "meat toppings" or answer == "meat":
                Order.append("- with Meat toppings")

        if answer == "pizza":
            Order[FOOD] = Pizza

            answer = input("With your Pizza, do you want Grilled chicken or Chicken?\n").lower()
            if answer == "Grilled chicken":
                Order.append("- Grilled chicken")
            if answer == "seasonal vegetables":
                Order.append("- seasonal vegetables")                

try:
    if Order[2]:
        print("You have ordered the following. Your order number is 294")
        print("")
        print("    ", Order[DRINK])
        print("    ", Order[FOOD])
except:
    pass

try:
    if Order[2]:
        print("    ", Order[2])
except:
    print("")
    print("No food or drink?! Get out!")

try:
    if Order[2]:
        print("""
        Your order should arrive within 10-50 minutes. If you wish to cancel,
        please contact us at 077 3475 8675309. Thank you for your patronage!
        """)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: I think you should just use argparse instead of hand rolling a stateful parser.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Here is the first part of your code with a `while (condition):`

```
Order = [ 'No drink', 'No food' ]
Yesses = [ 'y', 'yes', 'yep', 'okay', 'sure' ]
DRINK = 0
FOOD = 1

print("Welcome to Hungary house!")

print("")
print("First, let me get your drink order, if any.")

answer = input("Would you like something to drink? ").lower()

if answer in Yesses:
    print("What drink would you prefer?")
    print ("1: Fanta")
    print ("2: Coke")
    print ("3: Pepsi")
    print ("4: Sprite")

        correct = False

    while (!correct):
        choice = input("Please enter a drink from the menu above\n").lower()

        if (choice == "1" or choice == "fanta"):
            Order[DRINK] = "Fanta"
            correct = True
        elif (choice == "2" or choice == "coke"):
            Order[DRINK] = "Coke"
            correct = True
        elif (choice == "3" or choice == "pepsi"):
            Order[DRINK] = "Pepsi"
            correct = True
        elif (choice == "4" or choice == "sprite"):
            Order[DRINK] = "Sprite"
            correct = True


print ("You have chosen: " + Order[DRINK])
```

**Original answer:**
So if it's using `input()` you can get away with doing a while loop until the statement is true. So put all the code in a loop and fulfill the Boolean when correct. For example:

```
correct = false
while (!correct):
    var = input ("your statement")
    if var == "good":
        correct = true
#next stuff
```

Comment: Yup, away from computer right now and cruising mobile, I'll format your question soon!

Comment: @rdowg I just updated the answer with an exact and working code, let me know if it works on your end.

Comment: @jarrod-roberson - Agreed, the reason why I made a comparison with a reference is only so the asker could see the reference. Particularly in a `while` this, indeed, would be a very bad idea. I have updated the answer to reflect the most optimized code. Do you recommend other optimizations? I think: `if (choice == ("1" or "fanta")):` would also be a better solution, but for a beginning programmer, this may not work. You need certain editor

Comment: @iSkore could you show me an example for a menu order and how I should set it out

Comment: There is no `!` operator in Python, only `not`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop and break once you're satisfied:

```
drink = None
while drink is None:
    choice = input("Please enter a drink from the menu above\n").lower()

    if choice == "1" or choice == "fanta":
        drink = "Fanta"
    elif choice == "2" or choice == "coke":
        drink = "Coke"
    elif choice == "3" or choice == "pepsi":
        drink = "Pepsi"
    elif choice == "4" or choice == "sprite":
        drink = "Sprite"

Order[DRINK] = drink
```

Comment: I entered a random number to see if it would work, it did not work the code just moved on

Comment: It should ask the question again

Comment: This is the gist, but DRINK is set to 0 at the top, so I don't think that this conditional is going to fly?

Comment: Doh, I thought Order was a dictionary. Will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, for the drink part to continually loop over until the user enters something valid:

```
while choice != "1" or choice != "2" or choice != "3" or choice != "4":
    choice = input("Please enter a valid drink: ")
if choice == "1" or choice == "fanta":
    Order[DRINK] = "Fanta"
    if choice == "2" or choice == "coke":
        Order[DRINK] = "Coke"
    if choice == "3" or choice == "pepsi":
        Order[DRINK] = "Pepsi"
    if choice == "4" or choice == "sprite":
        Order[DRINK] = "Sprite"
```

I think this would work because it would keep iterating over the loop until the condition is met. And then once the loop is completed, it will execute the code below it.

Comment: Wouldn't this continue to loop if the user inputted "fanta"?

Comment: @Bink could you show me an example for a meal option

Comment: Yes. So you need to add more conditions. `or choice != "fanta"`

Comment: `while answer != "indian" or answer != "chinese" or answer != "italian"` you will then need to ask for the value of answer again.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    choice = input("Please enter a drink from the menu above\n").lower()

    if choice == "1" or choice == "fanta":
        Order[DRINK] = "Fanta"
        break
    if choice == "2" or choice == "coke":
        Order[DRINK] = "Coke"
        break
    if choice == "3" or choice == "pepsi":
        Order[DRINK] = "Pepsi"
        break
    if choice == "4" or choice == "sprite":
        Order[DRINK] = "Sprite"
        break
```

This is pretty clunky, but it's most in line with what you've already got.  I'd suggesting moving most of these items into lists like this, but that's a bit of a refactor for this answer.  Consider the below, but really all you have to do is stick your input into an infinite loop and then break when the user gets it right.

```
drink_list = ['fanta', 'coke', 'pepsi', 'sprite']
if choice in drink_list:
    break
```

Comment: Where should i input the bottom bit? @RobertRodkey

Comment: The bottom bit is a part of a suggested refactor to make this cleaner.  If you stored your items in a list it would be easier to check if the user input is in that list.  To be clear, a working answer is the top code and the top code only.